# Inject dependency on both a registered type and a concrete object into a constructor with Unity

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a class `MyClass` with the following constructor:

```
public MyClass(IRepository repository, AnotherClass anObject) { ... }
```

The interface `IRepository` is registered at application startup with Unity 2 to be mapped to a concrete class:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IRepository, MyConcreteRepository>();
```

Now, the concrete instance of the second parameter of the constructor is always different depending on application context. So I cannot register `AnotherClass` to be a specific instance at startup nor does it make sense to let Unity create an object of that class with its default constructor which would happen if I call:

```
container.Resolve<MyClass>()
```

This resolves to `new MyClass(new MyConcreteRepository(), new AnotherClass())`.

What I am looking for, if I have some given concrete object `anObject` of type `AnotherClass`, is a way to tell Unity to resolve `MyClass` to

```
new MyClass(new MyConcreteRepository(), anObject)
```

without permanently registering the instance `anObject` in the container.

Is this possible and how?

Thank you for help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `ParameterOverride`:

```
var myClass = container.Resolve<MyClass>(new ParameterOverride("anObject", anObject));
```

In case it's not clear given the names used in the sample, this assigns the object anObject to the parameter named "anObject" in the MyClass constructor.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Unfortunately, it ignores the overridden parameter silently if I should carelessly change the parameter name from `anObject` to something other like `myObject` and Unity creates a new default object. In my special situation I would prefer to get a "ParameterNotFound" exception or something like that. But I guess I have to live with that.

Comment: Yeah - I wish unity would throw an exception in this case as well.  Another thing to look out for is that if you subclass MyClass and use a parameter override, it will ripple through any base() constructor chains.